# How to activate color-coding and intellisense in new PyCharm project?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I created a new project in PyCharm, however, color coding is not carrying over. Intellisense seems to not work either.

I have already tried switching themes and messing with the source directory, but nothing changes.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjsLo.png)

I would expect the above screenshot to be color coded based on the theme I am using, darcula in this case. Also, boto3 is not installed, so I would expect an error outside of a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was main.py was seen as a text file even though *.py is seens as python. Weird, don't know how that happened, but I went to File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types, deleted that association and it worked.